# Sliderinput to create number of selectinput drop down menus

Tags: r, shiny, lapply

I want to use the lapply function to set the number of times it should the function should run to create drop down menus

the input in lapply function should be from a sliderinput selected by user

currently I am incorrectly placing in lapply function 1:input$slider. I want to use the range in lapply as ( 1:user defined number coming from sliderinput) in both server and ui side.

How can I use an input from slider on both ui and server side?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
 sliderInput("integer", "nooftabs:",min=1,max=10,value=2),
lapply(1:input$integer, function(i) {

  uiOutput(paste0('choose_tab1', i))
 })
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 lapply(1:input$integer, function(i) {
  output[[paste0('choose_tab1', i)]] <- renderUI({
  selectInput(paste0('tab1',    i),"tab:",list("Select"="","a"="file","b"="left"))
 })})
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: did u try wrapping the lapply in an observe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an event depends on an input, it needs to go through the server:

```
require("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("integer", "nooftabs:",min=1,max=10,value=2),
  uiOutput("select_inputs")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  observeEvent(input$integer, output$select_inputs <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:input$integer, function(i){
      selectInput(paste0('tab1',    i),
                  "tab:",list("Select"="","a"="file","b"="left"))
    })
  }))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```